# WAMP Apache Alias Directory Not

Tags: apache, github, wamp, alias

I have set up my WAMP server and also created an Apache alias for the folder I need local host to access.  When I access localhost I get to the WAMP server and all is working fine.  The phpMyAdmin works as well.

The problem is that when I attempt to access local host/project I just get to a white page which does not pull my files so I can view them on the web.

I am using GitHub to do this.  Here is an example of what my alias looks like

> c:/users/name/documents/github/project

The alias name is actually `localhost/project`.

All seems to be hooked up, no issues with WAMP access, the actual alias or any other aspects except for when I try and access the local host/project

Any help, guidance or gneral feedback (I am willing to try about anything at this point) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the syntax you are using for your alias declaration? Are there quotes, spaces in the path, etc.?

Comment: Sure I am just not sure exactly what you mean, or more which place do you want me to pull that info from??  Do you want the syntax from the Edit Alias file in wamp?  Just want to make sure I post the right info

Comment: In `C:\wamp\alias\` is there a file called `<yourAlias>.conf`? I was thinking the first line of that, where it will say something like: `Alias /project "c:/wamp/www/vhosts/project"`

Comment: Yes, here is what shows on that:  
Alias /project/ "c:/users/ian/documents/github/project/" 

<Directory "c:/users/ian/documents/github/project/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: You could try removing the trailing `/` on the Alias name. `Alias /project "c:/users/ian/documents/github/project/"`

Comment: I did try that in both the alias file on my c: and also in the WAMP alias file.  When I remove the trailing / I know get a 404 page error instead of a blank page so it did change something.  Any suggestions on resolving the 404 not that trailing / is removed?

Comment: ok try this `You could try removing the trailing / on the Alias name. Alias /project "c:/users/ian/documents/github/project"